# how can I extract element from a list in python

Tags: python

how can I spit this array in python:

```
a = [1.7, 2.3, 3, 4.5, 5.5, 3.6]
```

to this:

```
b = [1.7, 2.3, 5.5]
c = [2.3, 4.5, 3.6]
```

i want to split my array to it.

Comment: Is `b` correct above? Why not `b= [1.7, 3, 5.5]`?

Answer (score 0):

loop over each index and ad to list `b` or `c` if the index is even or odd

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if i%2 == 0]
c = [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if i%2 != 0]
```

Comment: please lock at my question again

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) syntax to select the even(odd) indexed elements from a list. Basically, Python allows you to construct new lists by indexing other lists in a special way.

For a list `a`, you can do `a[start:stop:step]`. This will construct a new list with the elements `a[i]`, for `i` in `range(start, stop, step)`.

Omitting `start` and/or `stop` causes them to default to `0` and `len(a)` respectively. `step` defaults to `1` if omitted.

So for even indexed elements:

```
a[::2]
```

Which means take the elements for the start to the end of the list, with a 'step' of 2.

and for odd:

```
a[1::2]
```

Which means take the element from the second to the end of the list, with a 'step' of 2.

E.g.

```
a = [1.7, 2.3, 3, 4.5, 5.5, 3.6]
b = a[::2]
c = a[1::2]
```

Comment: please lock at my question again

Comment: @JabarMajidu why?

Comment: Maybe because they are under the impression that their teacher then won't find this question.